# PHP CURL to send XML to Rightmove API with SSL

Tags: php, xml, ssl, curl

ive been struggling with this over the weekend and i cant figure out what the problem is. I'm trying to use RightMoves new API to send XML to them. I am using a template they provide so i know the markup is correct.

They provided me with the following files :

a JKS File.
A Personal Information File.
a PEM file.
A p12.

I cant get any examples and i have not done anything with SSL before, this is the PHP i came up with after reading a few tutorials :

```
  <?php
  $xml = file_get_contents("myxmlfile.xml");

  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__)."mypemfile.pem");

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://adfapi.adftest.rightmove.com/v1/property/sendpropertydetails");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://adfapi.adftest.rightmove.com/v1/property/sendpropertydetails');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $ch_result = curl_exec($ch);
  echo "Result = ".$ch_result;
  curl_close($ch);

?>
```

I get no response at all in my net console, can anyone please shed some light i really need to move on! Thanks in advance.

Comment: try it with verbos true

Comment: @ChetanAmeta Made no difference at all.

Comment: have you check verbose process output in console?

Comment: @ChetanAmeta Console is blank

Comment: @ChetanAmeta i managed to see the error : 60SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificateResult =

Comment: try use the option `CURLOPT_SSLCERT` rather than `CURLOPT_CAINFO` - also include `CURLOPT_VERBOSE=1` as this will echo useful info to your terminal